# Il se passe ou ça se passe ?

Tags: pronoms

> J'ai regardé un film d'horreur.

And then:

> **Il** se passe dans un hôtel.

or

> **Ça** se passe dans un hôtel ?

Why?

Answer in English please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either of them.

In the first sentence, the pronoun ***il*** refers to the movie:

> *Il se passe dans un hôtel* = *Le film se passe dans un hôtel*.

In the second sentence which is less formal, the neutral pronoun ***ça*** refers to what happens in the movie.

> *Ça se passe dans un hôtel* = *L'action se déroule dans un hôtel*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: *На Здоровье* ;-)